# Why is my text position aligning to the viewport

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align y text to a project, but whenever I do, the text aligns to the viewport. Whenever I try aligning the text, the text moves with the viewport vertically.

```css
header {
    height: 900px;
    background-image: url('../img/large-banner-image.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
}

span {
    font: 60px Pacifico, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.Header-Type {
    vertical-align: -16px
}

img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 17px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 62px;
    right: 13px;
}

h2 {
    font: 22px Raleway, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

p {
    font: 36px Raleway, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 90px;
}

.Phone {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -567px;
}

.Down-Arrow {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: -574px;
}

<.content-alt {
    float: left;
    margin: -600px 1800px
}

> .content-alt2 {
    display: none
}

.content {
    display: none
}

.content2 {
    display: none
}

.alternate {
    display: none
}

.other {
    text-align: center;
}

.near-bottom {
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    word-spacing: 30px;
}

.footer {
    font: 16px HelveticaNeue, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.Image {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1> <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="img/focus.png"/><span>Focus</span></h1>
    <p>A landing page for your app with focus</p>
</header>

<div class="Phone">
    <img src="img/iphone.png" />
</div>

<div class="content-alt">
    <h2>Great Feature</h2>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        <br> adipiscing elit. Mauris interdum velit vitae
        <br> nulla molestie eu. </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <h2>Great Feature</h2>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        <br> adipiscing elit. Mauris interdum velit vitae
        <br> nulla molestie eu. </div>
</div>

<div class="content-alt">
    <h2>Another Great Feature</h2>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        <br> adipiscing elit. Mauris interdum velit vitae
        <br> nulla molestie eu. </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <h2>Another Great Feature</h2>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        <br> adipiscing elit. Mauris interdum velit vitae
        <br> nulla molestie eu. </div>
</div>

<div class="alternate">
    <h2>Get The App Today!</h2>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse fringilla fringilla nisl congue congue. Maecenas nec condimentum libero, at elementum mauris. Phasellus eget nisi dapibus, ultricies nisl at, hendrerit risusuis ornare luctus id
        sollicitudin ante lobortis at.</div>
</div>

<div class="other">
    <h3>“Focus is an app that is extremely useful. I would reccomend it to anyone.”</h3>
    <div>Kyle Turner, Blogger</div>
</div>

<div class="Image">
    <img src="img/people.png" />
</div>

<div class="near-bottom">
    <h4>Say Hi & Get in Touch</h4>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit suspendisse.</div>
</div>

<footer>
    <p>Contact Download Press Email Support</p>
</footer>
```

Any troubleshooting would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe a bit better what you're trying to accomplish?  It's not very clear for your question.

Comment: This code doesn't seem complete, can you post the complete source code?

Do you try to align vertically?Not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: Im trying to make the text align with the page and not move by vertical scaling

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have the paragraph element set to `position: relative`. In this case, relative to the viewport. Get rid of that. You shouldn't be using relative positioning unless y absolutely required.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/XvmAneo.jpg

the paragragh i used that to send the element up to align with the grid.

Text can be such a pain.

Comment: Then you'll have to look for a workaround. Text is insensitive to align when relative positioned.

Comment: Extra piece of advice, learn some good brand new tech: css grid, by the awesome Rachel. It will make your front-end dev much easier!! http://gridbyexample.com/video/

Comment: the problem still persists with the styles, of which i placed content and content alt

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the text to "vertical-align: middle" you should give it the display property: "display:table-cell" and its parent element the display property: "display:inline-table". That way your vertical align property will work without problems.

Comment: its not the vertical align thats messed up. Its those Great feature and another great reatures

Comment: Kev, can you help me further. This text is placing me at my wits end

Comment: Try to explain the problem one more time to me real slow, i would like to help you but i'm not quite sure what the problem exactly is.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpNaYR

Im trying to get the text of the great features to move with the viewport. As you can see there, if you move the viewport to the left or right, it doesnt move with the rest of the page. which is a problem. It should be moving.

Comment: Oh okay now i get the problem, well you cannot solve that problem with "position:relative". That is the reason why relative positioning does'nt get used for creating the content flow of a page. You need to set them up either with the "flex-box" property or with floating.

Comment: KevDev. I've changed the position relative with a float, is there something i'm missing?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpNaYR

Comment: KevDev...can we talk over skype. I'm at my wits end with this text. I tried floating the text and placing a margin in there to change the space. Not even allowed to use float. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with floating elements for responsiveness on the page, hope that helps!

```
header{
   height:250px;
   background-image:url('../img/large-banner-image.png');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center top;
}


span {
   font: 60px Pacifico, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 400;
}

.Header-Type{
   vertical-align: -16px
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 17px;
}

h1 {
   text-align: center;
   margin-top:60px;
}

h2 {
   font: 22px Raleway, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 700;
}

p {
   font: 36px Raleway, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 300;
   text-align: center;
}

.content-alt  {
   text-align:left;
   float:left;
   width:20%;
   margin-left:20%;
}

.content-alt2  {
   text-align:left;
   float:left;
   width:20%;
   margin-left:20%;
   margin-top:60px;
}

.content-alt2::before{
  clear:both;
}

.content  {
   text-align:left;
   float:left;
   width:20%;
   margin-left:20%;
}

.content2  {
   text-align:left;
   float:left;
   width:20%;
   margin-left:20%;
   margin-top:60px;
}
```